# ggplot group mean line

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to add a mean line for each group to bar chart. Receive same error each time:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Count' not found


ggplot(df_melted2  %>% 
         filter(EDNAME =='Blanchardstown-Corduff'), aes(Resource, Count, fill=Resource)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(~ EDNAME, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())  +
  geom_point(data = df_melted2 %>% 
               group_by(Resource) %>% 
               summarise(Mean_Resource = mean(Count)))
```

It works fine without the attempt to add the mean line:

```
ggplot(df_melted2  %>% 
         filter(EDNAME =='Blanchardstown-Corduff'), aes(Resource, Count, fill=Resource)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(~ EDNAME, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

Why is it not recognizing the column 'Count' and how did I get overall group mean lines in the chart?

[image]

Comment: Please `dput(head(df_melted2 ,30))` and paste the result in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Major oversight on my part. The summarized column must be the same name as the original and I had given it a new name.

```
ggplot(df_melted2  %>% 
         filter(EDNAME =='Blanchardstown-Corduff'), aes(Resource, Count, fill=Resource)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(~ EDNAME, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())  +
  geom_point(data = df_melted2 %>% 
               group_by(Resource) %>% 
               summarise(***Count*** = mean(Count)))
```